# Transform a table (list of associations) to a flat association

Tags: dataset, associations

I would like to transform a table like

```
{<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 11, "c" -> 111|>, <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 12, "c" -> 112|>, <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> 22, "c" -> 111|>}
```

into an association that has the same keys and as values a list of the values in the original association, i.e.

```
{<|"a" -> {1, 1, 2}, "b" -> {11, 12, 22}, "c" -> {111, 112, 111}|>}
```

The way I did that was via

```
keys = Keys[as[[1]]]
values  = Lookup[as, #] & /@ keys
AssociationThread[keys -> values]
```

Two questions:

- Is there a more straightforward way?
- if everything is wrapped in a Dataset, how can I do it (without reverting to Normal)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
as={<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 11, "c" -> 111|>, <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 12, "c" -> 112|>, <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> 22, "c" -> 111|>};

Merge[as, Identity]

(*<|"a" -> {1, 1, 2}, "b" -> {11, 12, 22}, "c" -> {111, 112, 111}|>*)
```

Comment: +1. For the second question... if we are given `ds = Dataset @ as`, then we can use `ds[Merge[Identity]]`.

Comment: @Algohi  Identity seems very poorly documented - is it just acting as a placeholder in this case?

Comment: Merge[expr,f], the function f is applied to lists of values that share the same key. Identity returns its argument. To understand that check this another solution: Merge[as, {#}[[1]] &]. And also check this: Identity[{1, 1, 2}]